# problema con el listof en java

Tags: java

tengo un problema que no logro solucionar y es porque me marca como error la palabra `of` cuando estoy creando una lista. Tengo importada la clase

```
List<Integer> numeros = List.of(1,2,3,4);
```

Comment: List.of() está disponible a partir de Java 9. Que versión de java estas usando?

Comment: ¿Cuál es el mensaje de error que estás recibiendo?

Comment: The method of(int, int, int, int) is undefined for the type List. ese es el mensaje de error que estoy recibiendo

Comment: abre el cmd en windows o el terminal en linux y escribe javac -version, coloca la salida acá

Comment: tengo la version 8 . de ahi el porque no me lo toma. tendre que actualizarlo entonces

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar este código que te permite hacer lo que necesitas.

```
 List<Integer> numeros = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5);
```

Comment: muchas gracias. saludos